# ::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - only on my machine

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, vpn, connection-reset

I have a jQuery ajax POST that sends data to the server and **immediately** I get a `::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` message in the console:

```
POST http://www.example.com/casino/update net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

In the browser Network tab, the request shows this
[image]

Request Headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,la;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5 Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 470559 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 Cookie:__RequestVerificationToken=8Cwc2L37NPyl1F4DzZmbAWsA9hIdIVg7QvasixpkG7H1LCCLs1L9nw0x6UChMi29rmrILiPC696f5Z7L1O-L-ZaNLGXd6fCnFIc04HZ0hDs1; ai_user=lJP/J|2022-10-08T16:05:46.372Z; ai_session=6tmMv|1667568222358.7|1667569384189.9 
Host: www.example.com 
Origin: http://www.example.com 
Referer: http://www.example.com/casino/b696197f-3836-44f0-8061-8c19fbff321a/settings Request-Id: |AERzm.7NhxS 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

There is nothing in the Preview or Reponse tabs

In the error callback, the `error` object contains the following:

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

... so it's not very apparent what the issue is.

Here's the code

```
   $.ajax({
            
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method, // always POST in this case
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

            beforeSend: function () {
                toolbar.SaveButton.startLoaderIcon();
            },

            complete: function () {
                toolbar.SaveButton.stopLoaderIcon();
            },

            success: function (result) {
                toolbar.SaveButton.stopLoaderIcon();

                SettingsPage.renderResultMessages(result, "Casino", null, null);

                //update Casino Operating Systems table with saved data
                reloadCasinoOperatingSystemDataTable(result.CompatibleOperatingSystems);
                reloadTrackerLinksDataTable(result.TrackerLinks);
                reloadCasinoGameTypeDataTable(result.CasinoGameTypes);
                reloadCasinoBankingProvidersDataTable(result.CasinoBankingProviders)

            },
            error: function (error, type, httpStatus) {
                toolbar.SaveButton.stopLoaderIcon();

                var message = "The Casino was not saved because the following error occurred:<br />" + error.status + ' ' + error.statusText + ' - ' + httpStatus;
                SettingsPage.renderErrorMessage(message, "Save Error");

            }
        });
```

**This only seems to happen to me** - not to any of my users. It happens in Chrome and Firefox, so doesn't appear to be a browser issue.

Again, this only happens to me, so it can't be a server or header issue. When I debug locally on `localhost:[portnumber]/...` it works fine, so it does not appear to be anything to do with the app

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

- I tried everything described [here](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-err-connection-reset-error)
- I tried deactivating all extensions in Chrome
- I tried on two other machines on my network with success (so it's my machine!)
- I tried turning off every feature in Norton Security and turned off Windows Defender
- I turned off Nord VPN
- I read about 73 SO posts that mention ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
- I even tried in Edge!

Only remaining variable seems to be Windows 11 (the other two machines are Windows 10)

UPDATE 2:
I tried Wireshark to check for network traffic and followed [this turorial](https://documentation.meraki.com/General_Administration/Other_Topics/Using_Chrome_Devtools_with_Wireshark) but it seems that a network connection is not even being established.
Ajax GET requests work fine...

UPDATE 3:
Uninstalled Norton Security Ultra and rebooted. Same sh**.
When I view one of my photos on photos.google.com and hit SHFT+D to download it, I get "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

Comment: If it only happens to you, and in multiple browsers then I'd guess it's a local network-level issue. Do you have a LAN or router based ad blocker or other network traffic monitor? Pi-hole for example.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, but no ad blockers. No extensions whatsoever in FF. Out of interest, I tested on my old Windows 10 dev laptop and it works fine. So it's something on my Win11 machine. At least I now know it's specific to this machine and isn't a server/network issue

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the problem was Nord VPN! Even with it DISCONNECTED, it was causing the issue.

When I closed the app, things worked again. Opened the app in a disconnected state and the errors began reoccurring.

I established that it is NordVPN's "Threat Protection". When I deactivated it, things work. reactivate it, things stop working.
[image]

Even with all of its settings deactivated, the problem persists
[image]
I had to turn it off completely for things to work

I went as far as uninstalling Norton and trying again (maybe they conflicted), but the above Nord setting still had precisely the same effect.

Maybe this is a unicorn situation. Perhaps someone else will experience it and find this useful.